# Create an aggregate Nagios check based on values from other checks

Tags: linux, nagios

I have multiple checks for ten different web servers. One of these checks is to monitor the number of established connections (using neststat and findstr to filter for ESTABLISHED). It works as expected on servers WEB1 through to WEB10. I can graph (using pnp4nagios) the TCP established connection count because the output is an integer. If it's above a certain threshold it goes into warning status, above another it becomes critical.

The individual checks are working the way I want.

However, what I'm looking to do is add up all of these connections into one graph. This would be some sort of aggregate graph or SUM of all of the others.

Is there a way to take the values/outputs from other checks and add them into one?

```
Server  TCP Connections

WEB1    223
WEB2    124
WEB3    412
WEB4    555
WEB5    412
WEB6    60
WEB7    0
WEB8    144
WEB9    234
WEB10   111

TOTAL   2275
```

I want to graph only the total.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios itself does not use performance data in any way, it just takes it and passes it to whatever you specify in your config. So there's no good way to do this in Nagios (You could pipe the performance output of nagios to some tee command which passes it to pnp4nagios and a different script that sums everything up, but that's just horrible to maintain).

If i had your problem, i'd do the following:

At the end of your current plugin, do something like

```
echo $nconnections > /some/dir/connections.$NAGIOS_HOSTNAME
```

where `nconnections` is the number of connections the plugin found. This example is shell, replace if you use some different language for the plugin. The important thing is: it should be easy to write the number to a special file in the plugin.

Then, create a new plugin which has code similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
WARN=1000
CRIT=2000
sumconn=$(cat /some/dir/connections.* | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}')
if [ $sumconn -ge $CRIT ]; then
    echo "Connection sum CRITICAL: $summconn connections|conn=$sumconn;$WARN;$CRIT"
    exit 2
elif [ $sumconn -ge $WARN ]; then
    echo "Connection sum WARNING: $summconn connections|conn=$sumconn;$WARN;$CRIT"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Connection sum OK: $summconn connections|conn=$sumconn;$WARN;$CRIT"
    exit 0
fi
```

That way, whenever you probe an individual server, you'll save the data for the new plugin; the plugin will just pick up the data that's there, which makes it extremely short. Of course, the output of the summary will lag behind a bit, but you can minimize that effect by setting the normal_check_interval of the individual services low enough.

If you want to get fancy, add code to remove files older than a certain threshold from the cache directory. Or, you could even remove the individual services from your nagios configuration, and call the individual-server-plugin from the summation plugin for each server, if you're really uninterested in the connection count per server.

EDIT:

To solve the nrpe problem, create a `check_nrpe_and_save plugin` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$($NAGIOS_USER1/check_nrpe "$@")
rc=$?
nconnections=$(echo "$output" | head -1 | sed 's/.*you have \([0-9]*\) connections.*/$1/')
echo $nconnections > /some/dir/connections.$NAGIOS_HOSTNAME
echo $output
exit $rc
```

Create a new `define command` entry for this script, and use the new command in your service definitions. You'll have to adjust the sed pattern to what your plugin outputs. If you don't have the number of connections in your regular output, an expression like `.*connections=\([0-9]*\);.*` should work. This check_nrpe_and_save should behave just like check_nrpe, especially it should output the same string and return the same exit code, and write to the special file as well.

Comment: Thanks very much, Guntram. This is excellent. There is a piece I failed to mention and that is that I am checking each server by running the nscp.exe client (check_nrpe to execute a powershell script on Windows). Unfortunately I won't be able to echo $nconnections to a shared location to complete the check you have written which I'm sure would work.

Comment: Is there another way I might be able to output the data from each check_nrpe on the Nagios server itself? This would be ideal - instead of having them locally on each server. If it was a netstat command from Nagios itself, your solution would work perfectly. Unfortunately, netstat is running on each web server individually.

Comment: Thanks again, Guntram. I had troubles with this - output=$($USER1/check_nrpe "$@") - is that line correct? I also tried $USER1$ but that didn't work (error 127 out of bounds). When i specified it explicitly to the path of the check_nrpe, I got an unknown error (i think due to $@).

Comment: The error was "Incorrect command line arguments supplied NRPE"

Comment: Yes, i forgot to put NAGIOS_ in front of it (all $XXX$ parameters in nagios are exported as $NAGIOS_XXX shell variables). Yes, "$@" is correct, it means "pass all parameters to this script to the command line of what's called here without changing anything". Have you set the x bit on the new script? What happens if you manually run `new_script -H WEB3` compared to `check_nrpe -H WEB3` ?

Comment: Also, i managed to make 2 stupid mistakes in one line of code - the one beginning with nconnections (was: $nconnections). Sorry about that. I changed my code, please retry :)

Comment: root@NAGIOS:/etc/nagios/libexec# sh check_nconnections -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
head: cannot open `I' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `(0,4,1,73' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `2012-12-17)' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `seem' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `to' for reading: No such file or directory
I (0,4,1,73 2012-12-17) seem to be doing fine...